# How to run oracle user defined functions using node.js

Tags: node.js, oracle, user-defined-functions

I am trying to run an user defined function on oracle db through node.js using oracledb driver. My oracle function is declared in PACKAGE z_1419_pkg as

```
FUNCTION GET_CUSTOMER_INFO(P_COMPANY_NAME VARCHAR2, P_COMP_CODE VARCHAR2) RETURN QC_UTL_PKG.CURSOR_TYPE
  IS
    C QC_UTL_PKG.CURSOR_TYPE;
    V_COMPANY_NAME COMPANIES.COMPANY_NAME%TYPE := TRIM(P_COMPANY_NAME);
    V_COMP_CODE    COMPANIES.COMPANY_CODE%TYPE := TRIM(P_COMP_CODE);
  BEGIN
    C := QC_CV_PKG.COMPANIES_BROWSE(NULL,V_COMP_CODE,V_COMPANY_NAME,NULL,NULL,
                                    NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
                                    NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    RETURN C;
  END;
```

and my node.js code is

```
exports.syncOracle = function (req, res) {

  var oracledb = require('oracledb');
  var bindvars = {
    p1:  'BM Dusters',
    p2: 'bmduster', 
  };
  oracledb.getConnection({
    user          : 'uname',
    password      : 'password',
    connectString : 'locahost/TEST' },
      function (err, conn) {
        if (err) { console.error(err); return; }
        console.log('success');
        conn.execute('SELECT Z_1419_PKG.GET_CUSTOMER_INFO(:p1, :p2) from dual;' ,bindvars ,function (error, rows) {
          if (error) {
            console.log('ERROR: ' + error);
          }
          return res.status(200).json(rows);
      });
  });

};
```

but I am getting

> ERROR: Error: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Can somebody tell me what is wrong with my code. I could not find any documentation or example on how to use oracle functions with oracledb driver.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When executing an SQL statement through an API such as this you shouldn't put a semi-colon at the end of the statement, so the call to `conn.execute` should be:

```
conn.execute('SELECT Z_1419_PKG.GET_CUSTOMER_INFO(:p1, :p2) from dual',
             bindvars ,function (error, rows) {
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks Bob. Your answer was helpful.But now I am getting a different error

Error: NJS-010: unsupported data type in select list
I modified the code as follows,
conn.execute('SELECT Z_1419_PKG.GET_PARTS_INFO(:p1, :p2) from dual' ,bindvars, {outFormat: oracledb.OBJECT}, function (error, rows) {

still getting the same error

Comment: I'm guessing it's because this function returns a custom cursor type. You might change it to return SYS_REFCURSOR instead, which node.js might be able to handle. However, because it's a new problem I suggest you post it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated, node-oracledb 0.6 doesn't support user defined types.  You could write a 'wrapper' function in PL/SQL that decomposes your data into the basic types that are currently supported.